# How to disable the floating code editor widget in Android Studio/IDEA?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

[image]

Like the picutre with RED frame.
When I try the find the String, It often drives me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need t disable **Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance | Show code lens on scrollbar hover**

[image]